# Prove that the supremum of the set of the sequence is bigger or equal then the limit of the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

The question: Let $a_n$ with $n=0, 1, 2,\dots$ be a sequence that converges to $a^*$. We define also $A=\{a_n | n=0, 1, 2, \dots\}$. Prove that $\sup A \ge a^*$.

I've tried to prove it by contradiction with the formal definition of the limit and the supremum, but without success.

Comment: Proof by contradiction isn't a bad idea. Supposing $\sup A < a^{\ast}$, what then about the neighborhood $U := \big(\sup A, + \infty)$ of $a^{\ast}$. How could the original sequence convergence to $a^{\ast}$ if it never enters this neighborhood?

Comment: @joeb Superb comment

Comment: @joeb Thanks for your comment. I understand what you mean. My struggle is in finding an epsilon which results in $a_n > supA$ so that I have my contradiction.

Comment: Still assuming $\sup A < a^{\ast}$, why not try $\varepsilon := a^{\ast} - \sup A > 0$.